# How do I do a post request with related serializers Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have model `Package` with `Supplier` and `PackageSize`,  foreign keys and a field to which is also a foreign key of a `Shipping model` which contains where the supplier wants to ship the package so to make sure I a user can submit the whole information in one request, I created my serializers and linked them like such.

`serializers.py`

```
from users.models import Supplier
from packages.models import Package , PackageSize , ShippingLocation , Shipping

    class ShippingLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model= ShippingLocation
            fields = ['latitude','longitude']
        def create(self, validated_data):
            return ShippingLocation(**validated_data)

    class PackageSizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model= PackageSize
            fields = ['length', 'width' ,'height' ,'weight']
        def create(self, validated_data):
            """
            docstring
            """
            pass

    class ShippingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        location = ShippingLocationSerializer(source='location_set')
        class Meta:
            model = Shipping
            fields = [
                'first_name', 
                'last_name',
                'phone_number',
                'email',
                'street_address',
                'village',
                'district',
                'country',
                'location'
                ]
        def create(self, validated_data):
            """
            docstring
            """
            pass

    class SupplierPackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        size = PackageSizeSerializer(source='size_set')
        shipping_location= ShippingSerializer(source='to_set')
        class Meta:
            model = Package
            fields = ['supplier', 'name', 'size', 'shipping_location', ]
            read_only_fields = ['supplier']
        
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user =Supplier.objects.get(username=self.context['request'].user)
            return Package(supplier=user, **validated_data )
```

and created my views like such

`view.py`

```
from rest_framework import generics
from packages.models import Package
from .serializers import , SupplierPackageSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class SupplierPackageViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SupplierPackageSerializer
    queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models    
from django.conf import settings
from users.models import Supplier

class ShippingLocation(models.Model):
    latitude = models.IntegerField()
    longitude = models.IntegerField()

class Shipping (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number =  models.CharField(max_length=14)
    email = models.EmailField()
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    village = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.OneToOneField(ShippingLocation , default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE )

    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class PackageSize(models.Model):
    length = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()

# Create your models here.
class Package(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Envelope'),
        ('2', 'Parcel'),
        ('2', 'Soft'),
        ('2', 'Freezed'),
    )
    TYPE = (
        ('1', 'CREATED IN SYSTEM'),
        ('2', ''),
        ('2', 'Soft'),
        ('2', 'Freezed'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey( Supplier , on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    to =  models.ForeignKey(Shipping, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    size = models.ForeignKey( PackageSize, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="1", choices=TYPE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

the challenge is when I submit the data it is validated very well but it cannot be saved and I get this error

```
TypeError at /supplier/package
Package() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size_set'
```

Comment: Show us your models

Comment: I have added the packages app model.py

Comment: `AssertionError at /supplier/package
It is redundant to specify `source='size'` on field 'PackageSizeSerializer' in serializer 'SupplierPackageSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.` thats the error i get. when i remove the source attribute like they say i get a `ValueError at /supplier/package
Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('length', 30), ('width', 234), ('height', 23), ('weight', 32)])": "Package.size" must be a "PackageSize" instance.`

Comment: You will also have to override create method and create related object

Comment: The foreign key names are `size` and `to` but you are using `size_set` and `to_set` in your serializer source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model Package has foreign key to PackageSize ( only one size per package) so source is not `size_set` but just `size`

```
    size = PackageSizeSerializer()
```

---

EDIT:

You will also have to override create method on serializer to save related object as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) in writable nested serializer

Something in a line of

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        size_data= validated_data.pop('size', None)
        if size_data:
            package_size= PackageSize.objects.get_or_create(**size_data)[0]
            validated_data['size'] = package_size
        return Package.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT!

serializers.py

```
class StringSerializer(serializers.StringRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        return value

class SupplierPackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        item1 = StringSerializer()
        item2 = StringSerializer()
        size = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        shipping_location= serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta:
            model = Package
            fields = ['supplier', 'name', 'size', 'shipping_location', ]
            read_only_fields = ['supplier']
        # add this  
        def get_size(self, obj):
            return PackageSizeSerializer(obj.item1).data
        
        def get_shipping_location(self,obj):
            return ShippingSerializer(obj.item2).data
```

DOCS:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield

So basically The StringSerializer() class is a way to return a string representation of the model data.

While SerializerMethodField This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.

Comment: Any link to an expalnation?

Comment: serializerMethodField  : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield        https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield